# Return HTML in JSON format from included php file

Tags: php, json, ajax

I've been trying to pass HTML back in a JSON object from my server, which I have finally managed to get working.

I'd now like to be able to pass back HTML from an *included* file but can't work out how to do it....is it possible?

My index.html looks like this:

```
<head>
<script src="ajax.js"></script> 
</head>
<body> 
<div class="main-content"> 
<p>Some content to be replaced</p>
</div> 
</body>
```

My javascript ajax call is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://example.com/process.php',
  data: formData,
  success: function(rtnData) {
    $('.main-content').replaceWith(rtnData['html']); // Redraw content
  },
  error: function(rtnError) {
    console.log('there was a problem');
  }
});
```

My process.php file is here:

```
<?php
$returnVal['html'] = include 'test.php';
echo json_encode($returnVal);
```

And finally, my test.php file is:

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="content">
    <p>The simple sum 5 + 4 = <?php echo 5 + 4;?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When this runs, it returns nothing in `rtnData['html']` and I see the console log 'there was a problem'.

If I change `$returnVal['html'] = include 'test.php';` to `file_get_contents('test.php');` it returns the HTML, but the php is returned as text without being executed, so my HTML is replaced with `The simple sum 5 + 4 = <?php echo 5 + 4;?>` instead of `The simple sum 5 + 4 = 9`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? I need to leave test.php as an external file; I can't change that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One posiible way is: you forget about `dataType: json` and return plain html from your `process.php`.

Contents of `process.php` will be just:

```
<?php
include 'test.php';
```

Ajax success will be:

```
success: function(rtnData) {
    $('.main-content').replaceWith(rtnData); // Redraw content
}
```

If you still need to return json - you have to [buffer output](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) from `test.php`:

Contents of `process.php` will be:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'test.php';
$returnVal['html'] = ob_get_clean();
echo json_encode($returnVal);
```

Ajax success in this case stays the same.

Comment: Thanks a million u_muider....i'll give that a try and accept your answer as soon as I can. Regarding just passing back HTML rather than JSON, if I did that, what's the best way to pass back an error? Would I just send back a 500 internal server error header along with some HTML or is that a bit of a hack?

Comment: Why not, but in case of 500 status your `error` handler will be called in ajax, not `success` one.